# Finding angle from two Vector2 points

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to get an angle from two Vector2 positions.

The points are found by the following raycast code:

```
RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(groundedPos.transform.position, Vector3.down, 1, lmask); // lmask is only the blocks
Vector2 firstPos = hit.point;

RaycastHit2D hit2 = Physics2D.Raycast(groundedPos.transform.position + new Vector3(5f, 0, 0), Vector3.down, 1, lmask);
Vector2 secondPos = hit2.point;
```

How would I get an angle from these two Vector3 points?

I would then need to change the rotation of my object after this.

Edit:

Flat ground:

[image: Flat]

Not flat:

[image: not flat]

As you can see in the images, the red raycasts are where the raycast codes hit and they are displayed, the black square with the circle colliders is the player, and the two blocks is the thing I'm trying to change the rotation of. It is fine on flat, as you can see. But non flat it is messed up.

Comment: [Vector3.Angle](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Angle.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First a general issue with your code is the `maxDistance`. You are passing in `1` as the maximum distance for both your raycasts but your image shows that this might not hit the ground if it isn't flat

=> one of the positions might be "invalid" since the raycast doesn't hit the ground and therefore the value would just be a default `(0, 0)` which will mess up the rotation.

you either want to wrap this properly and do e.g.

```
var hit = Physics2D.Raycast(groundedPos.transform.position, Vector2.down, 1, lmask);
var hit2 = Physics2D.Raycast(groundedPos.transform.position + new Vector3(5f, 0, 0), Vector2.down, 1, lmask);

if(hit.collider && hit2.collider)
{
    var firstPos = hit.point;
    var secondPos = hit2.point;
    
    ...
}
```

or rather use `float.PositiveInfinity` as maximum distance for the rays so they will always hit something.

```
var hit = Physics2D.Raycast(groundedPos.transform.position, Vector2.down, float.PositiveInfinity, lmask);
var hit2 = Physics2D.Raycast(groundedPos.transform.position + new Vector3(5f, 0, 0), Vector2.down, float.PositiveInfinity, lmask);

var firstPos = hit.point;
var secondPos = hit2.point;
...
```

---

Then alternativ to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75066827/7111561) you can also use

```
var direction = secondPos - firstPos;
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, Mathf.Atan2(direction.y, direction.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg);
```

which might be slightly more efficient.

Or simply set

```
transform.right = direction;
```

---

Or in case this is about a `Rigidbody2D` you would rather go through

```
rigidbody2D.MoveRotation(Mathf.Atan2(direction.y, direction.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg);
```

Comment: When I do this my code looks like this: `groundedPos.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, (Vector2.SignedAngle(Vector2.right, step - original)));`, but it does not look right. (I'm going to add an image onto the question showing what is wrong for the moment) :D  ((Using the answer below)

Comment: Instead of using float.PositiveInfinity is it the same to use Mathf.Infinity?

Comment: @Jerry looking into the [source code](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/a935c76939be457b82c70f54fe2cc7dd40fb9090/Runtime/Export/Math/Mathf.cs#L167) => it is exactly the same yes

Answer (score 0):

Once you've got the two positions, find out the angle from the starting point to the second point, then apply the Euler rotation, rotating around the z-axis ..

```
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler ( 0, 0, Vector2.SignedAngle ( Vector2.right, secondaPos - firstPos ) );
```

Note - if you are trying to rotate a child of a GameObject, you might be "double" rotating the object, which is what it looks like in the images you updated your post with. If the colliders are attached to a child object, do you need to rotate that object as well?